# dc.js: Composite Chart filtering/labeling

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following composite chart made in dc.js:
[image]

```
  barChart
    .dimension(savingsDimension)
    .colors('#009900')
    .centerBar(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d.value; });

  barChart2
    .dimension(savingsDimension)
    .colors('#000099')
    .centerBar(true)
    .elasticY(true)
    .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d.value; });

  var lineChart = dc.lineChart(compositeChart)
    .dimension(savingsDimension)
    .colors('red')
    .useRightYAxis(true)
    .renderDataPoints({
      radius: 3,
      fillOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeOpacity: 0.8
    });

  var xUnits = data.map(function (d) {return d.short_date; }).sort();

  compositeChart
    .width(1300)
    .height(350)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(xUnits))
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .xAxisLabel('Month')
    .brushOn(false)
    .elasticY(true)
    .margins({left: 80, top: 10, right: 190, bottom: 80})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(1160).y(220).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .compose([barChart, barChart2,
      lineChart
    ]).renderlet(function(chart){
      chart.selectAll("g.x text")
        .attr('transform', "rotate(-65)")
        .attr('x', -20);
    });

    barChart.group(fSavingsDimensionGroup, ' First Savings');
    barChart2.group(sSavingsDimensionGroup, 'Second Savings');
```

The first thing I am having trouble with is making it so that I can select an x-range on this composite chart which will then filter all of my other charts. Right now, I can select certain bars and filter it that way, but I can't select a range like in this example: http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/filtering.html

I tried using `.controlsUseVisibility(true)` but it just errors out.

Also, even though I have `.centerBar(true)` on both my bar charts, the labels still aren't centered. Not sure what I am doing wrong there.

**Edit #1:**

Changed the code to:

```
compositeChart
    .width(1300)
    .height(350)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([savingsDimension.bottom(1)
     [0].billing_period_start, savingsDimension.top(1)
     [0].billing_period_start]))
     [0].billing_period_start, savingsDimension.top(1) 
     [0].billing_period_start))
    .xAxisLabel('Month')
    .elasticY(true)
    .margins({left: 80, top: 10, right: 190, bottom: 80})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(1160).y(220).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
    .renderlet(function(chart){
      chart.selectAll("g.x text")
        .attr('transform', "rotate(-65)")
        .attr('x', -36)
        .attr('y', -20);
    });

compositeChart.xAxis().tickFormat(d3.time.format('%m-%Y')).ticks(24);
compositeChart.xUnits(d3.time.months)
```

And the chart now looks like:
[image]

The bars are weirdly spaced out and I have no idea why. 
I can now select a range on the chart, but it doesn't actually do any sort of filtering to the chart or any other chart on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the filtering behavior is selected by the type of x scale, so to get continuous brushing you could use a quantitative scale such as `d3.time.scale()`, convert your dates to date objects, and then use `xAxis().tickFormat()` to display them the way you want.

[Here is the feature request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/348) to allow the range brush on ordinal charts. It is mainly a question of how to design the feature in a general way.

You are moving the tick labels with your renderlet, so you should adjust the displacement there in order to center your labels.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the response and for being so active on SO.
I changed the dimension for these charts to instead use date objects and when I use `.x(d3.time.scale())` on the compositeChart, it makes the chart look like this: http://i.imgur.com/YV2Epcd.png. Trying to add `xAxis().tickFormat()` makes the chart error out.

Comment: Hmm yeah, date scales are hard to get right. No one gets them the first time. You also need your `xUnits` to match, it looks like in your case `d3.time.months`. Google around and you'll find more examples. I wanted to answer your question but I don't think I'm going to hold your hand through the whole learning experience, sorry.

Comment: The tickFormat error is [probably this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#why-does-everything-break-after-a-call-to-xaxis-or-yaxis)

Comment: I think the issue I am having is that I can't use `d3.time.months` as the scale because the x-axis needs to be `month-year`. I was able to mess around with it and get it to look different, though. I will update my answer with the changes I made.

Comment: You could get there with the d3.time stuff, but again, it's a big topic. You'll find a lot of other questions and answers about it here on SO.